# How to view multiple cameras using cv_camera?

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am a ros newbie that is trying to work with cameras. My question is how can I scale up the use of cv_camera so that I can use multiple cameras at the same time? My understanding is that since cv_camera will try to open the device specified by the device_id parameter, I cannot try to run multiple instances of the node since it will just refer to the same parameter.

Just to test this theory, I tried to run 'rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node 0' and 'rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node 1' with two cameras connected, but they just showed the same device. Any insight or advice would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: The solution was to use rosrun and specify the device name and a new node name using parameters:
e.g. 'rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node __name:=test  _device_id:=1'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288227/how-to-view-multiple-cameras-using-cv_camera?/) by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try this instead:

```
rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node _device_id:=0 __name:=cam1
rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node _device_id:=1 __name:=cam2
```

You were passing a regular un-named command line argument in and it was getting ignored, and the default camera 0 was getting used.

http://wiki.ros.org/cv_camera#Parameters

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) on 2018-04-11**:
Thank you for the response, When I tried to run both commands in separate terminals, the first node stopped working and posted this error. '[ WARN] [1523458344.803396303]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node registered with same name]'

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-11**:
@Coppermind you have to give the nodes different names otherwise one node gets shut down. See section 3 of http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-04-11**:
I updated the rosruns to provide a `__name` for each node.